# Radius of Cluster for DenStream algorithm on Normalised Data Points

Tags: algorithm, stream, cluster-analysis

I am trying to implement a clustering algorithm that uses DenStream's method for calculating radius of a cluster using sqrt(|SS|/N - (|LS|/N)**2). However when implementing the algorithm, the value (SS/N - (LS/N)**2) always result in a negative number and hence I can't get the radius using this equation.

This is especially so if I am using a normalised data of range [0,1]. Since each value is < 1, the squared of the value will be smaller and hence the LS is always greater than SS. Is there something wrong with my understanding of the radius calculation? I've been stuck at this particular calculations for some time :(

LS: Linear Sum of vector points SS: Squared Sum of vector points